# What is the idiomatic way for an API to return part of the data now, and part of the data later?

Tags: reactjs, express, http

Suppose my back-end is using two (legacy) APIs the responses of which I want to combine. One returns the majority of the data and is quite fast. The other is slow, and only returns one feature for the dataset. Also, the response of the first API is required for the request to the slow API to be meaningful.

What I'd like to do, is that the back-end would return the result of the fast API instantly, then wait for the slow API, and then combine the two into a second response also containing the missing feature. If I'm correct, this would be accomplished somehow with the asynchronous HTTP pattern. However, I'm having troubles conceiving a solution while still keeping my API stateless, like all REST APIs should be.

So far: the following is the best concept I have been able to come up with:

1. A client (browser) sends a request to my API.
2. My API retrieves the data from the fast API, and sends a response like: `{dataFromFirstAPI: {...}, linkToPoll: "/api/whatever/xyxzzy"}` with status 202.
3. My API sends a request to the slow API, waits for response, processes the response and combines it with the result from the fast API. After that it returns the data to a request at `linkToPoll`.
4. Meanwhile the client will poll `linkToPoll` until it receives an appropriate response and body.

I have a few questions about the above approach:

1. Is it an antipattern to also return some other data in a 202 response (point 2. above)?
2. Is there any convention on what the polling URL should be?

One approach would be for the client to send two requests, but this would create state for my API.